# WPF Application Icon from another project

Tags: wpf

There is solution with two projects: **WPFProject** and **WPFResources**. WPFProject has MainWindow.xaml. WPFResources has picture **logo.png**. How can I set **Icon** property for main windows in XAML markup from project **WPFResources**?

Comment: Is the image compiled as embedded resource?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [pack URI syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Something like:

```
Icon="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/logo.ico"
```

Comment: General format would be `pack://application:,,,/{project};component/{folder}/{fileNameWithExtension}`

Answer (score 5):

Let's consider a Visual Studio solution structured like this:

[image: Solution Structure]

- a WPF desktop client project (named `Main` in the example)
- a class-library project (named `Shared` in the example) containing shared code and resources.

Let's assume the Shared project includes an image file called `icon.png` which we want to 
set as the `Main` application icon. The image is stored in the `Resources` folder.

To do so:

1. First the *Build Action* for the `icon.png` file must be set to *Resource*.

[image: Set Build Action to Resource]

2. Specify the window icon using the [Pack URI](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) for the resource, either in the `MainWindow` constructor (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8254591/2299407)):

```cs
this.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Shared;component/Resources/icon.png"));
```

or directly in the XAML for `MainWindow`:

[image]

Comment: In my case, setting the image to `Resource` happen the image to 'disappear' from the SolutionExplorer but it was 'stil there' when I searched for it in the WindowsExplorer folder. Also had to reference the project `Main` to the `Share` (on SolutionExplorer, go to `Main` project, expand it, right mouse click inside it, click on `Add Project Reference` and check box of the `Main` project) and rebuild the project.

Comment: This helped me too... although, in my case I had multiple projects, e.g. Project A calling Project B (WPF) to open the MainWindow... 
I added the Shared Project. Then I had to add the Shared Project reference to both Project A and Project B, rather just in Project B.