# How to set window icon in code behind in wpf?

Tags: wpf, icons, code-behind

In xaml it is :

```
  <View:BaseWindow.Icon>
    /VBDAdvertisement;component/Images/logoVBD.png
  </View:BaseWindow.Icon>
```

I want to convert it into code behind.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change title bar image in WPF Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101895/how-to-change-title-bar-image-in-wpf-window)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like

```
myWindow.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/VBDAdvertisement;component/Images/logoVBD.png"));
```

You may need to qualify the path more though.

**Edit:** As i thought the path should be in [pack-uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) format:

```
"pack://application:,,,/VBDAdvertisement;component/Images/logoVBD.png"
```

Comment: yes, it is : myWindow.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/VBDAdvertisement;component/Images/logoVBD.png")); Thanks :)

Comment: To avoid the ugly "pack..." strings have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource

Answer (score 12):

This is the correct way to do it (assuming MyIcon.ico is placed on the root folder of a WPF project named MyApplication):

```
Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;component/MyIcon.ico");
myWindow.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

This is also what actually happens when you set the Icon property for the window in XAML.

When just setting the Icon to a new Bitmap, it will not be rendered smoothly and correctly, but instead quite a bit pixelated.

Answer (score 8):

Try this its absolutely working for both png as well as ico image format.

```
window.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("LiveJewel.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream);
```