# set icon for showdialog setting

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

Is there a way to add an icon to a Dialogbox.

This is where i create the settings for the Dialogbox:

```
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.WindowStartupLocation = 
WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
settings.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
settings.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
settings.Title = "System Error";
//settings.(set my icon here);
status.UpdateMessage(ex.Message, $"{ex.Message} To the products list");
_window.ShowDialog(_status, null, settings);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming we are talking about the icon on the very left side of the title bar.

One way would be like this (inside your ExpandoObject constructor):

```
Uri iconUri = new Uri("PathToYourIcon");
Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

For more details, see: [How to set window icon in code behind in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254281/how-to-set-window-icon-in-code-behind-in-wpf)

You should also be able to set the Icon attribute of your Window in your XAML template. A dialog should just be a Window like any other after all.